# How to create a custom view in Android?

Tags: android

I need to create a custom view with several standard views. For example a single object made of one TextEdit and two Buttons. This custom view shoud behave as a black box once added to an activity.

I'm new to android and I couldn't find any resources how to make that. All I could find is how to draw some graphics (rectangle, line, point) on the canvas.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class MyCustomView extends View {

    public MyCustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {

    }
}
```

Does anybody know how to do that please ?
Thanks.
Cheers,

Comment: `single object made of one TextEdit and two Buttons` for this you need to extend a `ViewGroup` . Class depends upon arrangement you want to have so choose the layout as per your need it maybe a LinearLayout or something else

Comment: why won't you just make an usual layout wih [`layout-editor`](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor) or even create/paste raw XML, inflate it and if you really need a "black box" for framework then just set `focusable`, `cancelable`, `clickable`, `selectable` and all other unneeded "`-ables`". these will block any state (style/look) change and any touch dispatched to this `View`